# Find elements that appear in more than k sets in python

Tags: python, set, intersection

I am implementing a basic spell-correction system and I have built an inverted index for my domain's language, where every character bigram is mapped to a list of words that contain that bigram.

Now I want to find all words that share more than 3 character bigrams with the given word `w`. So the main problem is: given a set of lists, how can one efficiently find elements that occur in 3 or more of them?

For example, given sets:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') , ('a', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), ('b', 'c', 'z', 'y'), ('e', 'k', 'a', 'j')
```

I like to get the output:

```
('a', 'e')
```

since `a` and `e` have each appeared in more than 3 sets.

I would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Show your code and your expected output

Comment: Read about [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: @ycx I added an example.

Comment: @stovfl That didn't help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    ('a', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
    ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'),
    ('b', 'c', 'z', 'y'),
    ('e', 'k', 'a', 'j'),
]
c = Counter()
for e in data:
    c.update(e)

# print(c)
# for k, v in c.items():
#     if v >= 3:
#         print(k, v)
```

You get the output by using this (or something similar):

```
>>> [k for k, v in c.items() if v >= 3]
['a', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @Ralf. You can use dicts to construct a histogram

```
someCollection = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') , ('a', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), ('b', 'c', 'z', 'y'), ('e', 'k', 'a', 'j')]
hist = {}
for collection in someCollection:
    for member in collection:
        hist[member] = hist.get(member, 0) + 1
```

Hist now is:

```
{'a': 3,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 2,
 'd': 1,
 'e': 3,
 'f': 2,
 'g': 2,
 'h': 1,
 'z': 1,
 'y': 1,
 'k': 1,
 'j': 1}
```

Which can be sorted with `sorted(hist.items(), key = lambda x[1]) # sort along values`